# Pulling the a specific row number in an inline query table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, fetch, offset

I have a database which I need to flip the first 15 values from rows into columns for a specific report.

I have my primary query which pulls the universal data and then does a Left Outer Join on an inline query.

The inline query looks as follows:

```
Left Outer Join
(Select t.a,
        t.b,
        t.c,
        CASE WHEN t.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cnt
 From   MyTable t
 Order by t.StartDate DESC
 Offset 0 Rows Fetch Next 1 Rows) g1 On p.a = t.a
                                     And p.b = t.b
                                     And p.c = t.c
```

However, when I try to run the query, I get

> "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

indicating the close of my inline query.

Comment: CASE WHEN t.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cnt...  Case when t.d = what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `case`, you have incorrect suntax

```
CASE WHEN t.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cnt
```

What should `t.d` be equal to?

e.g.

```
CASE WHEN t.d = "test" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cnt
```

or

```
CASE WHEN t.d > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Cnt
```

You also might be missing `ONLY` after `Rows`

```
Offset 0 Rows Fetch Next 1 Rows ONLY)
```

Comment: The problem with the CASE WHEN was a typo for the message on my part.  That was fine.  The problem was the ONLY after ROWS.  THANK YOU!!!